# A little doubt about MASQUERADE and SNAT/DNAT

Tags: iptables

I know what SNAT and DNAT means.
And I know when I want to config a local net server open service to internet, I should use:

- SNAT to help to change the packets coming from local net server to the router's address.
- DNAT to help to change the packets coming from internet to the local net ip of the server

But when we share network using MASQUERADE, we don't need to config the DNAT for these packets coming from internet. Some articles says the MASQUERADE is the same as SNAT except for auto find router's external ip.But why MASQUERADE doesn't need the DNAT configuration? And suppose MASUQERADE can do these thing for us, why iptables doesn't auto set SNAT for us when we set DNAT?

**Edit**

I just have a new question. Suppose two user in the local net browsing the same web page, and the clients ports that they opened is the same. When the web page server response packages to the router, how does the router know the packages is belonged to which user?

Comment: You seem to assume snat is on the lan side and dnat on the wan (internet) side, but no, it means the [s]ource side and the [d]estination side. Packets coming from your internal server should be snated to the outward wan ip (the router's internet ip) to then communicate with internet hosts (clients or servers), and packets coming from internet (clients or servers) will be snated to the router's lan ip to then communicate with hosts on your lan (such as your internal server). Dnat is more rarely used.

Comment: When you masquerade, the router masquerades as your internal server, so packets trying to reach the server just needs to reach the router's ip (without msaquerading, the internet send things to the router ip and the router then dnat to the appropriate internet server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both SNAT and DNAT do address translation both for incoming and outgoing packages, using the connection tracking (`conntrack`) facility of the kernel. So if the kernel detects that a packet in the reverse direction belongs to a NATed connection, it will do the reverse translation automatically, without a special rule for it.

That's why e.g. a single SNAT rule is enough (though it doesn't hurt if you have a DNAT rule for the other direction).

And yes, MASQUERADE is basically SNAT with the address taken from the interface. To quote `man iptables-extensions`:

> Masquerading is equivalent to specifying a mapping to the IP address of
>   the interface the packet is going out, but also  has  the  effect  that
>   connections  are  forgotten  when the interface goes down.

BTW, I find it simpler to remember that SNAT = Source NAT (changes the source address of the packet), and DNAT = Destination NAT (changes the destination address of the packet).

**Edit**

(Normally, you should ask new questions as a separate question).

`netstat` only shows connections between applications running on the local computer, and other hosts. It doesn't show the kernel connection tracking, you can find information about this in `/proc` (e.g. `/proc/net/nf_conntrack`) of with additional utilities from the `conntrack` package.

The networking layer doesn't know anything about "users". A connection consists of the source address, the source port, the destination address, and the destination port. That's all the networking layer knows about. It does NAT (Network Address Translation) by replacing the source/destination address, and also by replacing the destination/source (i.e., local) port number with some other number if that port is already in use.

So two users on different hosts with identical ports (on their machine) that are noth NATed will get different ports on the NATing host. Two users on the same machine will always use different local ports in the first place, so that is never a problem. The same if one user opens two connections at once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the tips about how to remember SNAT/DNAT is  verify helpful! I'm curious about how to capture the forward connections using netstat command, but when I do netstat -nat, I can't find anything for the forwarded connections,can you tell me how to achive this ?

Comment: I just have a new question. Suppose two user in the local net browsing the same web page, and the clients ports that they opened is the same. When the web page server response packages to the router, how does the router know the packages is belonged to which user?

Comment: @Frio The [`conntrack`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/conntrack.8.html) tool can be installed to report on the tracked connections and their states. `conntrack` isn't all NAT though so you would use options to report on those connections that are hitting the NAT rules.

Comment: Thank you verfy much for your reply!! I will have a try about this tool immediatly, it's very cool. Can you help to answer the second quesion in the comment please?

Comment: I was confused why many tutorials don't show the creation of a `DNAT` rule thus making it seem that `SNAT` and `MASQUERADE` was sufficient to also do the inverse mapping. When you do provide an explicit `DNAT` rule does that override the default behaviour? What's the precise interaction?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I would assume that there are two lookups, first for an explicit rule, then for the "reverse implicit" rule, but I'd need to read the kernel code to verify that (which is something you can do, too).

Comment: That seems the case, but DNAT by itself cannot implement address-restricted NAT. So it seems that if you wanted to implement address restricted then, one would require to use conntrack module on the prerouting chain.